# Is there a word for “to be able to trust”, because “anvertraubar” does not exist?

Tags: single-word-request, adjective, suffix

I want to use the suffix *-bar* to transform the word *anvertrauen* (*to trust something to somebody*) to change it meaning to *to be able to trust*. As a native German speaker this sounds so right in my ears, i.e. *anvertraubares Kapital* (money to trust).

However, this word is not listed anywhere, so it does not exist? Is there a more correct form using vertrauen, any good short alternative, or is it fine to use *anvertraubar*?

Here are some sample sentences:

> Ich vertraue dir Geld an. Ich kann dir X Euro anvertrauen. X Euro sind bei dir **anvertraubar**.

So, the word I'm seeking is describing the money, not the person.

Comment: Was willst Du sagen? Bezieht sich das "anvertraubar" auf das Kapital oder die Person, die das Kapital kriegt? Dann wäre die Person vertrauenswürdig. Oder geht es um die Anlageform? Dann würde ich eher "sicher" wählen.

Comment: @Robert: "To be able to trust" klingt nach einer Fähigkeit desjenigen, der vertrauen kann. Vertrauensvoll. Money to trust klingt aber nach Geld, das man anvertrauen will.

Comment: I would not say it does not exist, but it admittedly is not used very often See e.g. https://books.google.de/books?id=dYAaAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22anvertraubar%22&hl=de&pg=PA687#v=onepage&q=%22anvertraubar%22&f=false

Comment: I'd say "solventes Geld" would be possible. (?)

Comment: Du kannst hier Fragen auch auf deutsch stellen.

Comment: I have hopefully clarified the question and suggest that it not be closed.

Comment: To clarify things up: "Ich vertraue dir Geld an. Ich kann dir X Euro anvertrauen. X Euro sind bei dir **anvertraubar**". I hope now it's easier to understand what I mean. So, the word I'm seeking is describing the money, not the person.

Comment: @CarstenS Das weiß ich. Ich finde es sollten sich aber auch Leute zurecht finden, die gerade erst mit der deutschen Sprache angefangen haben.

Comment: @Beta Unfortunately, no.

Comment: He looks for the adjective that says "this (money) can be trusted to you", as a property / ability of the money. i.e. a tiger would not be "anvertraubar" to a child and a iambic pentameter not to a vegan lifestyle. See it as some sort of "compatibility" between the things in question and evaluates it from the POW of the former.

Comment: @Mark Exactly!!

Comment: I think you mean: "an adjective for 'able to be entrusted to someone/something'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, 'anvertraubar' does exist. Dictionaries just don't list all possible or rare derivations of words. But 'anvertraubar' is a correctly formed and comprehensible adjective. It requires a copular verb (Kopulaverb: sein, werden, bleiben,…) to which it is a predicative adjective (anvertraubar sein), and this will usually require a dative object to form a complete statement:

```
    {Etwas/Jemand}ᴺᴼᴹ ist {jemandem/etwas}ᴰᴬᵀ anvertraubar.
```

> Das Geld ist dir anvertraubar. (not: 'bei dir anvertraubar')

Attributive use in a noun phrase:

```
    der/die/das {jemandem/etwas}ᴰᴬᵀ anvertraubare {etwas/jemand}
```

Technically, the adjective describes the subject or the noun, but on the semantic level it is of course a statement about the person/thing that can be entrusted with the subject. That's just in the meaning of the word: The prefix 'an-' in 'anvertrauen' signals the transfer of something in a trustful manner.

But there are also examples of different uses, e.g., to describe that trust can be put into something that is desirable or expected to happen in something. It is here somewhat close to "zutraubar" (which is also not listed in your dictionary).

> "Normalerweise ist es dem Prozess der Vertrauensbildung und der Pflege
>   der Beziehung gut anvertraubar, dass sich die in neuen Bekanntschaften
>   anfangs oft geschärfte Wirkungssuche schließlich verläuft." *(Nicole Diercks: "Nie mehr weg von mir! Stärker nach Burnout", 2015)*

Comment: Genau.* Anvertraubar* erscheint den meisten nur komisch, weil sie sich keinen sinnvollen Kontext ausdenken. Das ist aber garnicht so schwer! *Das Geld wird von einem Mitarbeiter befördert. Die Höhe des ihm anvertraubaren Betrages richtet sich nach seiner Erfahrung und dem Ermessen seiner Vorgesetzten.*

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is

> vertrauenswürdig

»Anvertraubar« is also a correct German word, but it means something else:

### anvertraubar

I never used this wird, and it is hard to find a context where this word is the right choice, but I try it:

> Dieses Konto beinhaltet **anvertaubares** Kapital.
>   This bank account contains **trustable** capital.

This means that the capital can be trusted (given in good conscience) to someone. So this word describes a property of the capital.

### vertrauenswürdig

This word is more common.

> Walter ist sehr **vertrauenswürdig**, ihm kannst du das Geld geben.
>   Walter is very **trustworthy**, you can give him the money.

This means that Walter is reliable. You can trust him. He is »worth to be trusted«. So this word describes a property of a person (or institution) to whom you are giving something valuable.

Comment: No you got me wrong, instead I really seek for "anvertraubar", since I want to describe the money, not the person itself. The problem I have is this word simply does not exist: http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/anvertraubar

Comment: @modiX Yeah, but Hubert still has the answer in there, even if he suggested the wrong word. Not that ‘being in the Duden’ is neither sufficient nor necessary for ‘being a German word’.

Comment: @modiX: Two important things: 1. There is no *ministery of official words* or something similar. If you think a word expressed exactly what ever you want to say, then use it. Don't mind if it is listed anywhere. There is no *official list of allowed German words*. 2. Duden is not the official dictionary of German words. There is no such *official* dictionary. If you find a word in Duden, then you know that it is in use and you know how to write it. If you don't find it, then two things can be he reason: a. you tried to spell it wrong, or b. it is new or rare.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I know for good Duden is not the any official database of German words. If you search for "anvertraubar" on Google (with quotes), you will realize the word is barely used and not listed anywhere at all. Whatsoever, I went for it.

Comment: @modiX it's rare, because the contexts where it appears are rare. And listing it is unnecessary as it follows standard wordbuilding rules while being uncommon (waste of space in dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

I find it very amusing that the other answer correctly states what you are looking for but says that that is not the answer.

You can indeed say *anvertraubar* in the situation you want to use it in. To be honest, I cannot think of a situation at all where I would use that kind of sentence in either German or English, but given your constraints, *anvertraubar* is the word you are looking for.

The suffix *-bar* is **productive** in modern German, so it is able to form new words according to the established rules. Otherwise, there would be no discussion about how dreadful the word *unkaputtbar* is.

Also note that *being an understandable German word* and *being listed in the Duden* are two separate properties. The first is neither sufficient nor required for the second.

(Are you really sure you want to say that, or is that some bank-y thing that I just cannot understand?)

Comment: I really want to say it this way, since it needs to be a short way to label the money field on a website. See my comment on dervonnebenaan's answer. Anyways, I'm happy I can use the word.

Comment: @modiX On a totally unrelated side note, can I +1 your user profile for using Vivi as a profile pic? (If it’s a different black mage from a different FF, consider the argument adjusted accordingly ;))

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but -bar is not the right suffix. The correct form is 
**vertrauenswürdig,** which translates into English as "trustworthy," rather than "able to trust."

Comment: It has no reference to the person, it has its reference to the money.

Comment: @modiX:  Some forms of money are more trustworthy, or  "vertrauenswürdig" than others. I wasn't referring to people either.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> X Euro sind dir anvertraubar.

(note: without the *bei* ) is correct, but a bit uncommon in german language. You could use instead the direct translation of *it can be trusted to you*:

> X Euro können dir anvertraut werden.
>
> X Euro kann man dir anvertrauen.

Comment: I would have picked the alternations of my context if possible. However I needed a short translation of "money to trust" and wanted to go for "anvertraubares Geld" instead of "Geld, welches anvertraut werden kann".